# iOS: Selecting multiple weekdays

Tags: ios, checkboxes

I am trying to create an interface where the user can select any number of weekdays. My initial thought was to create checkboxes, like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPIHhU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However, I soon realized that checkboxes don't exist in iOS. Doing this with switches seemed much too cumbersome for the user.

Should I design my own checkboxes for use in the application or create the interface in some other way?

Comment: How does the 'Alarm' app do it? (Assuming it does.)

Comment: it has a button that opens up a dedicated full-screen sheet with a tableview, but doesn't that seem like overkill? (http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/17/45/63429483589561/0/fix-iphone-alarm-clock-bug-find-alternative-alarm-app.w240.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it has a button that opens up a dedicated full-screen sheet with a
>   tableview, but doesn't that seem like overkill?

Apple actually does this in a lot of places throughout iOS. When the user has a choice between two or more options (and the options are not each other's opposites, where a simple switch could suffice), a full-screen table view with checkmarks is used.